# Content Security Policy violation event is not triggered

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm trying to setup CSP headers for my application. I have intentionally left out our CDN from `font-src`
and `style-src` directives so that violation is triggered. I can see the violations on the Chrome Dev Tools console but the request to the `csp-endpoint` specified in the header is not triggered. I have tried by setting the `report-uri` attribute but that didn't help either. I'm testing this on Chrome 84 which is supposed to support `report-to` directive. Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' www.tagmanager.google.com www.fonts.googleapis.com fast.fonts.net; img-src 'self' data: www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com; form-action 'self'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-to csp-endpoint

Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"http://localhost:8080/myapp/csp-violation-report"}],"group":"csp-endpoint","max_age":10886400}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. report-to endpoints should have a [secure context](https://www.w3.org/TR/reporting/#endpoints-url-member) (actually - https:). Non-secure endpoints will be ignored.
2. There is some [problems with resolving of localhost name](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#localhost), not all user agents treat it as trustworthy. The `localhost` should conforms to the [specific](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#potentially-trustworthy-origin) (para 5) name resolution rules (pls see [Let 'localhost' be localhost](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06#page-3) RFC update).

Briefly - try to use `https://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/csp-violation-report`. May be a secure http**s**: `https://localhost:8080/myapp/csp-violation-report` will be enough for Chrome (Chrome 84 [supports the report-to](http://csplite.com/csp/test229/#test) directive, but Firefox - does not).

Comment: Adding onto this with 2 debugging issues I ran into when implementing this on an apache server. 1. even though https://www.json.org/json-en.html says single quotes aren't allowed in JSON, when implementing the `Report-To` header, I was able to (and could only use) single quotes: `Header always set Report-To "{'group': 'csp-endpoint', 'max_age': 10886400, 'url': '/csp-violation-report-endpoint.php'}"`. 2. Client-side adblockers may block the POST to report the CSP violation. I was having issues with uBlock when testing my solution, but disabling uBlock worked fine.